# Logout, Shutdown and reboot freezes Debian 10 Buster fresh install, while for Stretch it worked fine

Tags: linux, debian, shutdown, debian-buster

Fresh install from net-installer amd64, KDE as Window Manager, unencrypterd boot, encrypted LVM over LUKS2, and a Win10 as dual boot.

All works fine so far, except whenever I try to logout from user, or halt / reboot - and it freezes.
Interestingly, while in freezing status and mouse/beyboaard are gone (even numlock light), I can still ping the frozen computer.

I can successfully restart/poweroff when I do *not* desktop-login, but go remotely ssh and there do as a the *very first* command:

```
sudo systemctl poweroff
```

But when I do this anything on filesystem or login into GUI and there even a simple logout it freezes.

My system is a Lenovo W541 (With the old Stretch Kernel all worked fine)

```
lscpu |grep -i model
Model:               60
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4810MQ CPU @ 2.80GHz

uname -a
Linux igor 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What I have done so faar:

- [Shutdown and reboot not working in Debian 10 Buster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536439/shutdown-and-reboot-not-working-in-debian-10-buster) suggests BIOS-Update, which I did but it did not help.
- I disabled [apci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001737/what-do-boot-option-noapic-and-noacpi-actually-do), with no improvement

  nano /etc/default/grub

  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noapci"

  update-grub
- I installed XFCE4, little help.

[Others](https://superuser.com/questions/1437586/debian-10-buster-computer-wont-power-off-completely-nor-suspend-hibernate) seem to have similar issues -. what am I to do, I am worried, that the freezing on shutdown and then hard poweroff via 5s powerbutton could harm filessystem integrity, esp. with lvm over luks setting.

---

UPDATE

while freezing, the kernel is reporting: "watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for XXs"

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879584/what-to-do-when-lspci-and-hwinfo-freeze-the-system) try to:

1. Disable acpi editing `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` appending `acpi=off` at the end of the string called `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

for instance `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"`

1. `sudo update-grub` to update your `grub.cfg` file, disabling forever acpi
2. Black list nouveau creating a new blacklist file with `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` with the following content

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

save and run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Now kill your system as u know and after reboot logout, reboot and shutdown should work as expected